# Selenium assertFalse fails with staleelementreferenceexception

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, testng, assertion, staleelementreferenceexception

I have a selenium test in Java and I am doing some assertions like that:

```
assertFalse(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//td[2]/div")));

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
try { driver.findElement(by); return true; }
catch (NoSuchElementException e) { 
return false; }
```

It´s the standard method Selenium is generating when export from IDE to Java Webdriver.

(Yes I want to assert that this element is not present)

I always get errors when I am testing at this above code line 
Error: stale element reference: element is not attached to the DOM

But when I put a thread.sleep in front of that step it works.
The fact I don´t get is that it is enough to wait 1 milli sec.
Is it typical to wait before an assertion? 
Is there another way to solve this? (Implicit wait is not helping here)
Greetings from Germany!

Comment: Share the code for `isElementPresent()`

Comment: Instead of adding as a comment update the actual question with this additional info for a proper analysis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are facing *staleelementreferenceexception* in `assertFalse()` function, to negate the [FalsePossitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) usecase you can induce *WebDriverWait* with [*ExpectedConditions*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) clause set to [*stalenessOf*](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html#stalenessOf-org.openqa.selenium.WebElement-) within `assertTrue()` function as follows :

```
Assert.assertTrue(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]/div")))));
```

### Explaination

The *ExpectedConditions* clause *stalenessOf* will check for the staleness of the element identified as `(By.xpath("//td[2]/div"))`. When the intended element becomes stale, you can check for `assertTrue(boolean condition)`. `assertTrue()` would assert that a condition is true. If it isn't, an *AssertionError* would be raised.

### assertFalse(condition)

If you still want to implement the [FalsePossitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_positives_and_false_negatives) case of **`assertFalse(condition)`** raising **Error** you still can :

```
Assert.assertFalse(new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.stalenessOf(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//td[2]/div")))));
```

Comment: Hi DebanjanB thanks for your answer. One last question: I now get an compilation error in your codeline for the "By" right after the stalenessOf expression.                                                                                                                                                                               "The method stalenessOf(WebElement) in the type ExpectedConditions is not applicable for the arguments (By)" So i need to change the isElementpresent methode?

Comment: @ArnoDonCalzone There was a bug in my code which I have corrected and should work flawless. Let me know the status.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your update. Works quite well. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I think, timeouts are not set to WebDriver. try this

```
assertFalse(isElementPresent(By.xpath("//td[2]/div")));

private boolean isElementPresent(By by) {
driver.timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
try { driver.findElement(by); return true; }
catch (NoSuchElementException e) { 
return false; }
```