# Selenium FindElements method Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, linktext

In my project I use `findElement(By.linkText("")).click();`
but in the web page I'm using, many links have the same name(btw I can use By.linktext only) so i want to know it its possible to navigate among the links which have the same name

Also when i use `List<WebElement> h=driver.findElements(By.linkText("Years"));` and print it:

```
[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (f5681889-d73a-4a0f-88e9-2e189491049b)] -> link text: Years],[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (f5681889-d73a-4a0f-88e9-2e189491049b)] -> link text: Years],[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (f5681889-d73a-4a0f-88e9-2e189491049b)] -> link text: Years],
```

update:
In the page im working on, every 2nd link text with the same name is where i would like to go to, also there isnt any difference in those links except their description eg:
link 1:
Years
ABC(description)

link 2:
Years
XYZ(description)
can i use the description as a condition in any way??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you observe the output:

```
[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (f5681889-d73a-4a0f-88e9-2e189491049b)] -> link text: Years],[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (f5681889-d73a-4a0f-88e9-2e189491049b)] -> link text: Years],[[[FirefoxDriver: firefox on LINUX (f5681889-d73a-4a0f-88e9-2e189491049b)] -> link text: Years],...]
```

All the elements are having the *linkText* as **Years**. So apperantly you can should be able to use:

```
List<WebElement> h=driver.findElements(By.linkText("Years"));
```

But, invoking `click()` on certain elements at times changes the [DOM Tree](https://javascript.info/dom-nodes) and the saved elements within the *list* may turn into [*stale elements*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44838538/staleelementreference-exception-in-pagefactory/44844879#44844879).

In these cases, [printing the link names may fail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44970712/getting-staleelementreferenceexception-while-trying-print-the-link-names/44972370#44972370) as well as [assertions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49231669/selenium-assertfalse-fails-with-staleelementreferenceexception/49233199#49233199).

Hence as per the best practices, you may like to invoke `click()` on the specific `linkTexts` as the necessity arises inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165). As an example:

- `cssSelector`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("element_css"))).click();
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("element_xpath"))).click();
  ```

Comment: In the page im working on, every 2nd link text with the same name is where i would like to go to, also there isnt any difference in those links except their description eg:
link 1:  
Years
ABC(description)

link 2:
Years
XYZ(description)

can i use the description as a condition in any way??

Comment: @SCS Yes in that case you need to locate the `<a>` tags with texts as **Years** uniquely with respect to the description text. But that sounds to be a completely different issue all together. Can you raise a new question as per your new requirement? Stackoverflow contributors will be happy to help you out.

Comment: That might be a problem cause the content of the site is generated using script according to what i searched in the search engine
Im not very familiar with javascript and how they generate search results
which kind of brings me back to my original question
or is there any other solution for this kind of purpose??thx
also i only see a red flag beside your answer

Answer (score 0):

so i couldn't find the solution to my original question, but as for the updated question i just iterated to the second element of the list i got using: List h=driver.findElements(By.linkText("Years"));
h.get(1).click();
although it would be much efficient if i could get the destination URL of all the links generated by the search engine